# a slow templated factory

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The code below shows a templated factory. It takes a functor-class and returns the `operator()`'s return-value.

The functor-class below returns a simple struct which in this case is huge: `ints.resize(10000000,0)`.

When I invoke this factory I get a huge slowdown. Especially when invoked very often like `for (size_t i=0,j=10000; i!=j; ++i)`. I suspect a return-by-value (even if it returns only by reference).

Can anybody enlighten me as how to fix this slowdown?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto generate_one(Args... args) -> decltype(T{args...}()) {
  T t{args...}; // <<---- this is so slow!!!
  return t();
}

// template<typename T, typename... Args>
// auto generate_one(Args... args) -> decltype(T{args...}()) {
//   auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
//   T t{args...};
//   auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
//   auto elapsed = end - start;
//   std::cout << elapsed.count() << '\n';
//   return t();
// }

struct product_t
{
  std::vector<int> ints;
};

struct initial_product_t
{
  product_t operator()()
  {
    product_t product;

    product.ints.resize(10000000,0);

    return product;
  }
};

struct updated_product_t
{
  updated_product_t(product_t & product)
  : product(product)
  {}

  product_t & operator()()
  {
    return product;
  }

  product_t & product;
};

int main()
{
  auto product = generate_one<initial_product_t>();

  for (size_t i=0,j=10000; i!=j; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << i << "/" << j << std::endl;

    product = generate_one<updated_product_t>(product);
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**

I've tried the following code after suggestions from other users. But got some compilation errors.

```
struct updated_product_t
{
  updated_product_t(product_t && product)
  : product(product)
  {}

  product_t operator()()
  {
    return std::move(product);
  }

  product_t product;
};
```

The error

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 stackoverflow.cpp -o test
stackoverflow.cpp:60:15: error: no matching function for call to 'generate_one'
    product = generate_one<updated_product_t>(product);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stackoverflow.cpp:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure
      [with T = updated_product_t, Args = <product_t>]: no matching constructor
      for initialization of 'updated_product_t'
auto generate_one(Args... args) -> decltype(T{args...}()) {
     ^                                      ~
1 error generated.
```

I don't understand where the failure is.

**Edit 2**

I've changed - after digging deep into lvalue and rvalue - the factory to

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto generate_one(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T{args...}()) {
  T t{args...};    // ^^
  return t();      // a reference to a lvalue or rvalue
}
```

And I changed the `operator()` as it now returns the product with `std::move`.

```
struct updated_product_t
{
  updated_product_t(product_t & product)
  : product(product)
  {}

  product_t operator()()
  {
    return std::move(product);
  }

  product_t & product;
};
```

With these changes I get fast execution.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using the vector to allocate 40mb 10000 times in a row?

Comment: How fast is it without the factory?

Comment: It's fast without factory. I allocate so much to have a greater slowdown/easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @user1587451 Yes, if you removed all code that allocated 40 mb 10000 lines in a row, it would be fast.  It is unclear what it is you expect the code to do, in so far as it clearly either creates 0.4 gb of data or copies around that much data.  We can tell you why your code is slow, but doing "what you want it to do" while "not being slow" requires you describe **what you want it to do**.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness is here:

```
product = generate_one<updated_product_t>(product);
```

You're doing an assignment of the large vector every time.  Here's one way to fix it:

```
int main()
{
    product_t product = generate_one<initial_product_t>();
    product_t* pp;

    for (size_t i=0,j=10000; i!=j; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << "/" << j << std::endl;

        pp = &generate_one<updated_product_t>(product);
    }
}
```

Or you can refactor `product_t` to hold a `shared_ptr` to avoid copying the data of the vector:

```
struct product_t
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> ints;
};

struct initial_product_t
{
    product_t operator()()
    {
        product_t product;
        product.ints = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(10000000);
        return product;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to reuse `product` instead of `pp`?

Comment: Could std::move help here without the extra allocation?

Comment: @ArtYerkes Sure, but `updated_product_t` would have to take `product_t &&`, and return `product_t`, and move into return.

Comment: The initial product as well as the updated product are the same value. I use it in a recursion. The pointer * pp really fix the problem but opens another problem as `pp` and `product` are not the same